# Using Python URLlib but request keeps timing out after 60 seconds - am I doing it right?

Tags: python, ajax, http, aws-lambda, urllib

I'm writing a program that will be run on AWS Lambda and makes geocoding requests to TigerDB. The "requests" module isn't installed on Lambda so I want to use the built-in "urllib" module. My code currently looks like this:

```
    address = "350 Fifth Avenue New York, NY 10118"
    url = "http://internal-tigerdblb-xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/tiger-db-api/geoloc?address="
    params = json.dumps({"address": address}).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=params, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

This code produces no errors, but it times out after 60 seconds! I seriously don't think a HTTP call should take more than 60 seconds. So I must be doing something wrong.

I also tried this:

```
    address = "350 Fifth Avenue New York, NY 10118"
    url = "http://internal-tigerdblb-xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/tiger-db-api/geoloc?address="
    request = urllib.request.Request(url + urllib.parse.quote(address), headers={"content-type": "text/plain"})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

but this times out too. What do I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with curl?

Comment: @Hiram I haven't. I'm unable to access the TigerDB server on my local machine - I can only do it through AWS.

Comment: I feel that the request is not getting authenticated and that is why getting timed out. do you access to the server log or any place where you can look at the failure?